# from models import WorldBorder ImportError: No module named 'models'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

Why it show the Error i follow to setup the GeoDjango tutorial everything is correct , why data is not going to load

Model Class:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class WorldBorders(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField), and
    # overriding the default manager with a GeoManager instance.
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "World Borders"

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Load.py

```
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from models import WorldBorder 

world_mapping = {
    'fips' : 'FIPS',
    'iso2' : 'ISO2',
    'iso3' : 'ISO3',
    'un' : 'UN',
    'name' : 'NAME',
    'area' : 'AREA',
    'pop2005' : 'POP2005',
    'region' : 'REGION',
    'subregion' : 'SUBREGION',
    'lon' : 'LON',
    'lat' : 'LAT',
    'mpoly' : 'MULTIPOLYGON',
}
world_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'))

def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(Pakistan, world_shp, world_mapping,transform=False, encoding='utf8')

    lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

Error loading data

```
from world import load
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ismail/mainFolder/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "/Users/Ismail/mainFolder/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Ismail/mainFolder/geodjango/world/load.py", line 3, in <module>
    from models import WorldBorder
ImportError: No module named 'models'
>>>
```

what is wrong in the tutorial of Django website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In load.py, change this line:

```
from models import WorldBorder # shoudn't it be WorldBorders with an s?
```

to:

```
# Assuming your appname is called 'world' and your 
# WorldBorders class is in world/models.py
from world.models import WorldBorders
```

The line above may change depending on what your Application Name is. If your application name is "world", then it should work. If you application name is "ApplicationName", then do this:

```
from ApplicationName.models import WorldBorders
```

Edit: Based on your file structure, I think your application might be called "geodjango" so maybe try:

```
from geodjango.models import WorldBorders
```

Comment: Yes , the WorldBorder class is in world/models.py and load.py is also in same directory , i have changed but it not work same error .    from  world.models import WorldBorder

Comment: @JonasDavid You should be importing WorldBorders (with the s), because the model has an s. Does it work when you try to do it with the s (i.e. from world.models import WorldBorders)?

Comment: @JonasDavid also, what is your application name? (go into settings.py and view the installed apps there). Do you just have one application, and is that application called world?